# I can check if a string is null-terminated but not check it isn't yet null terminated

Tags: c++, string, pointers, null-terminated

For the sake of me better understanding C++ strings, array and pointers; I want to know: Why is it that I can use a condition whereby I check if the index has reached the null-terminating character like this...

```
const char* myString = "Grandopolous";
for (int i = 0;;i++)
{
    if (!myString[i])
        break;
    else
        cout << myString[i];
}
```

So that works just fine. Here I am instead checking to see if the character equals something other than the null-terminating character and so I expect that if it doesn't the result should be not 0 and the condition should be true. but this does not work, and I simply cannot fathom why:

```
const char* myString = "Grandopolous";
for (int i = 0;;i++)
{
    if (myString[i])
        cout << myString[i];
}
```

This does not work on my machine and crashes, also it outputs a lot of unreadable error messages mixed with strange symbols. I don't think that part matters although it is the first time error have been printed to my console application instead of the debug console.

The reason I mentioned pointers is because I managed to get the condition to work using pointers instead of the array index syntax which I find much easier to read.

So could someone please help me understand why my first bit of code is valid and why my second is not.

Comment: Think about how this loop should terminate. Does anything in the first code sample stop the loop? How about the second?

Comment: You're never exiting the loop

Comment: c++: use `std::string`...

Comment: Please get into the habit of describing your problems using more descriptive phrases than "it doesn't work"

Comment: You forgot `else break;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Said already 15 minutes ago in the comments, and below as an answer.

Comment: Voting to close as "simple typographical error".  This question and its answer is very unlikely to be helpful to future users.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I decided to rephrase previous comments just case it wasn't yet entirely obvious to the OP. (It was edited right into the answer at the exactly same time I posted that comment.)

Comment: Thank you everyone I see the problem it was a duh thing I'm sorry.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Actually, I said "you got rid of the `break`" in my very first revision.

Comment: I don't know if this is off topic to distract you guys from answering or working or whatever but these forum things just seem horrible everyone is always criticizing and fighting each other on "who's smarter". Keep in mind I am not referring to myself being asked to ask questions in a more clear way for example. I understand that. but doesn't this bickering violet the how to ask a question section just as much as my noob question? It was such a small question and hours later people were still having the "last word" about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* work. The check for null isn't the problem.

Your program crashes because you got rid of the `break` so your program overruns the array then continues forever into the abyss.

Your debugger would surely have revealed this to you as you stepped through the program, observing `i`.

To reverse the logic of your first example, write:

```
const char* myString = "Grandopolous";
for (int i = 0;;i++)
{
    if (myString[i])
        cout << myString[i];
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Oh Thank You I was so confused I knew it had to be something so silly I was doing.

Comment: Or even (in this case) move the test where it belongs: `for (int i = 0;  myString[i];  ++i) { std::cout << myString[i]; }`.

Comment: Thanks that is really something i never though about I will do that in the future. @TobySpeight